# Templates instead of the cpp preprocessor to avoid linking?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Is it possible to use C++ templates to avoid linking against a library containing a function which is not ultimately called? For example, with code such as:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  void bar() { zod(); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.5 will reject it:
error: there are no arguments to ‘zod’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘zod’ must be available
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

Is an error compulsory here by standard? Is there any way using templates to achieve this; and so avoid cpp macros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing *linking* with *providing a prototype* for `zod()` (i.e. a declaration, e.g. by including a header file).

Many implementations will happily compile and link a program that has `inline` functions (or templates) which call functions without a definition. So, this works just fine (with at least MSVC 10, GCC 4.3 and GCC 4.5):

```
void zod(); // we need the declaration, but no definition

inline void bar() { zod(); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if the standard mandates it though. And of course it should also work with a template instead of `inline`, as long as the template is never instantiated.

Comment: +1. For that matter, non-inline functions which are never called will get stripped by many linkers, resulting in no problem. I'm also not sure of the standard status… it's gonna have something to do with "`odr-used`" though.

Comment: This looks good. It works both with templates and inline using Digital Mars Compiler 8.42n; and GCC 4.5, and 4.6.

Answer (score 2):

As the error implies, if `zod()` had a dependency on a template parameter then SFINAE would render this as not-a-problem.

As it stands, a declaration of `zod` must be available. Sorry.

If you had control of `zod` and didn't mind adding a dummy parameter to it, you could do something like this:

```
template <typename T, T dummy>
struct Foo {
  void bar() { zod(dummy()); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

But... major ew.

Comment: Thanks. I can in fact afford a declaration; just not a definition.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown anything in your example that needs any specialization of the code. In that case you can simply declare the function `inline`.

Perhaps there's more to the question that I'm not seeing; if so, please edit the question and provide more details.